# Upper bound for norm of Hilbert space operator

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

It is a standard result that for a bounded self-adjoint operator $T$ on a complex Hilbert space $H$, we have $\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}|\langle Tx,x\rangle|:=M(T)$, where $M(T)$ is called the [numerical radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range) of $T$. It seems that for any bounded operator on $H$, we have $||T||\leq 2M$. Why is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. We can be write 
$$
T = A + iB
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint operators defined by
$$
A := \frac 1 2 (T + T^+)\\
B := -\frac i 2 (T - T^+)
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sesquilinear forms. Especially a square form.

So let's say that $f:H \times H \to \Bbb C$ is a square form that $f(x,x)=\langle Tx,x \rangle$ then you can say that $\| f \| \le \|T \| \le 2\|f \|$.

By sesquilinear map we mean a map $\phi:H\times H\to\Bbb C$ with properties:

1. The map is linear to the first variable: the map $x \to \phi(x,y):H \to \Bbb C$ is linear.
2. The map is antilinear to the second variable: the map $x \to \overline{ \phi(x,y)}:H \to \Bbb C$ is linear.

Also, $\|f\| := \sup\limits_{\|x\|,\|y\|\le 1} \langle Tx,y \rangle$.